# Load Multiple Object in OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm new to OpenGL and now I'm learning to create an object. I'm trying to load more than one object, but only the last object appears.

```
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <math.h>

void Box (void){
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  glVertex3f(-0.14,-0.10,0.00);
  glVertex3f(0.10,-0.10,0.00);
  glVertex3f(0.10,0.30,0.00);
  glVertex3f(-0.03,0.30,0.00);
  glVertex3f(-0.14,0.00,0.00);
  glEnd();
  glFlush();
}

void Circle(float cx, float cy, float r, int segmen)
{
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  for(int i = 0; i &lt; segmen; i++)
  {
    float theta = 2.0f * 3.14f * float(i) / float(segmen);
    float x = r * cosf(theta);
    float y = r * sinf(theta);
    glVertex3f(x + cx, y + cy,0.0);
  }
  glEnd();
}

void CreateCircle(void) {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  Circle(0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 45);
  glFlush();
}

void Draw (void) {
  glPushMatrix();
  Box();
  glPopMatrix();
  glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.14,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(90.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    Box();
  glPopMatrix();
  glPushMatrix();
    CreateCircle();
  glPopMatrix();

  glFlush();
}

int main (int argc,char* argv[]){
  glutInit(&argc,argv);
  glutInitWindowSize(800,800);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGBA);

  glutCreateWindow("object5B");
  glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

In trying to searching in internet, I found something about object_list but I don't really get it. Hope you can help.

Comment: Why are you `glClear()`ing before each object instead of once at the beginning of `Draw()`?

Comment: OpenGL doesn't deal with objects. It just draws points, lines and triangles. One at a time, without any relation to the points lines and triangles it has drawn before and after. And if I had two cents for every time I've written this on SO, I could probably afford a really nice day trip.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I don't know how each gl function work, so I just put it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's just like what genpfault said, you clear the `COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` every time you draw an object which cause the earlier drawn object to be erased (the color) from the screen. You only need to call `glClear()` once at the beginning before you draw on the screen.

---

Anyway, i recommend you to search about modern OpenGL. The way you use OpenGL now is known by the name "immediate mode" which is bad, slow, and deprecated. Here's a [good site](http://www.open.gl)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your use of:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

You’re calling this in your Box() and CreateCircle() functions. Doing so WILL result in the problem you seem to be describing. The call doesn’t belong in those functions. It belongs at the top of your Draw() function, and nowhere else.